# Prove that $∀a, b, c ∈ \mathbb Z$ with $b \neq 0$, if $b|c$, then $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + c, b)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

> Prove that $∀a, b, c ∈ \mathbb Z$ with $b \neq 0$, if $b|c$, then $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + c, b)$.

I've proved it in the following way:

$\gcd(c,b) = b.$
Let $\gcd(a,b) = x$, $x|a$ and $x|b$
Since $b$ is the $\gcd$ of $c$,
if $x|b$ then $x|c$

Thus, $\gcd(a+c, b) = x = \gcd(a, b)$.

Was wondering if this is a solid proof. If not, is there anyway I can improve on this? Thanks for helping out

Comment: How do you know that there isn't a $y > x$ so that $y|a+c, b$? (Also you don't explicitly state that $x|a + c$ although, I'll grant you it is clear.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then since $b | c$, we have $d|c$ which implies $d| a+c$. Thus, $k=\gcd(a+c,b)\ge d$.

Now, $k | b$ and $k|a+c$. But $k|b \Rightarrow k|c \Rightarrow k|a$ (Because $k$ also divides $a+c$). Thus, we have $k$ divides both $a$ and $b \Rightarrow k\le d$

In conclusion, $k\le d $ and $k \ge d$ implies $k=d$, which was what was to be proved!

Comment: Thanks! your proof is so much more solid :D

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo you’re welcome! Many problems in number theory can be tackled using this technique actually.

Comment: how does k|b and k|b imply k <= d?

Comment: @PixelRain because it also implies k|d (which is the gcd of a and b) from which we conclude k<=d

Comment: Yeah I just saw that, so k >= d because d|a+c and d|b, so by definition of gcd d <= k as d divided both the elements of the gcd(a+c, b)?

Comment: @PixelRain yeah exactly

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion $\gcd(a+c, b) = x = \gcd(a, b)$ is not that clear from your previous parts.

One way to show the claim $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a + c, b)$ is to *split* the task into two parts:

$\qquad\qquad\gcd(a, b)|\gcd(a + c, b)\qquad$ and $\qquad\gcd(a+c, b)|\gcd(a, b)$

from which equality follows.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{rlr}
> \gcd(a,b)|b&\qquad\qquad(\text{by definition of }\gcd)&\qquad (1)\\
> b|c&\qquad\qquad(\text{by assumption})\\
> \Longrightarrow \gcd(a,b)|c&\qquad\qquad(\text{by  transitivity of }|)&\qquad(2)\\
> \\
> \gcd(a,b)|a&\qquad\qquad(\text{by definition of }\gcd)&\qquad(3)\\
> \\
> \Longrightarrow  \gcd(a,b)|(a+c)&\qquad\qquad(\text{by(2) and (3)})&\qquad(4)\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\Longrightarrow  \gcd(a,b)|\gcd(a+c,b)}&\qquad\qquad(\text{by(1) and (4)})&\qquad\color{blue}{(\text{I})}\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

We further obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{rlr}
\gcd(a+c,b)|b&\qquad\qquad(\text{by definition of }\gcd)&\qquad(5)\\
b|c&\qquad\qquad(\text{by assumption})\\
\Longrightarrow \gcd(a+c,b)|c&\qquad\qquad(\text{by  transitivity of }|)&\qquad(6)\\
\\
\gcd(a+c,b)|(a+c)&\qquad\qquad(\text{by definition of }\gcd)&\qquad(7)\\
\\
\Longrightarrow  \gcd(a+c,b)|a&\qquad\qquad(\text{by(6) and (7)})&\qquad(8)\\
\\
\color{blue}{\Longrightarrow  \gcd(a+c,b)|\gcd(a,b)}&\qquad\qquad(\text{by(5) and (8)})&\qquad\color{blue}{(\text{II})}\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

> We conclude from (I) and (II)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a+c,b)}
> \end{align*}